# Extension of Goursat's Lemma

Tags: group-theory

Consider $n \geq 2$ groups $G_1,..., G_n$ each having no non-trivial abelian quotient, and let $H$ be a subgroup
    of $G_1 \times ... \times G_n$ such that every projection map $H \to G_i \times G_j$ is surjective. Show that
    $H = G_1 \times ... \times G_n$.

Comment: What do you mean by the projection map $H \to G_1 \times G_2$?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the projections $H \to G_1$ and $H \to G_2$. Edited above now.

Comment: Nobody can help you if don't get the problem statement correct. It is still wrong.

Comment: I tried to give a simpler case of the problem I was originally trying to solve, and got it wrong. Sorry. This is the original problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a sketch of a proof for $n=3$. I'll leave you to sort out the general case, which you can do by induction on $n$.

$N_1 = \{ g \in G_1 \mid (g_1,1,1) \in H \}$. We want to prove that $N_1=G_1$. Since $H$ projects onto $G_1 \times G_2$ and onto $G_1 \times G_3$, for all $g,h \in G_1$, there exists $x \in G_3$ and $y \in G_2$ such that $(g_1,1,x)  \in H$ and $(g_2,y,1) \in H$. Hence, taking the commutator gives $([g_1,g_2],1,1) \in H$, so $N_1$ contain $[G_1,G_1]$, hence $G_1/N_1$ is abelian, and so $N_1=G_1$, as required. Similarly $N_2=G_2$ and $N_3=G_3$, so $H=G_1 \times G_2 \times G_3$.